# How to pass variable from one page to another unlinked page

Tags: javascript, php, post, cookies, get

Is it possible to ***pass a variable*** from one page to another ***without a form***, provided that the *first page **does not** have a link* (e.g. a button or other control where the user would click and would be redirected to the second page - so in a nutshell the first page does not directly link to the second page at all) ***to the second page***.

I ***can not use session variables*** because the first page and the second page are going to be visited by different users (so obviously in different sessions).

I ***do not want to use cookies*** either.

**So please suggest a solution other than cookies or session variables?**

Comment: What does JavaScript have to do with the problem, or with the intended solution?

Comment: @Joeppie I thought it might be helpful to solve the problem... as somebody had suggested solving the problem by local storage using JS!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that:

- Alice enters some data on page 1
- Bob must read that data on page 2
- Alice and Bob do not use the same browser on the same user account of the same computer

The last of these points I'm inferring from "*different users (so obviously in different sessions)*". Please clarify it is wrong.

Then the data must be stored on the server somewhere since there is no other connection between Alice and Bob.

1. You have to send the data from Alice's browser to the server. This is normally done using a form (but you say you don't have one … which rather begs the question of how the data is created in the first place). You could also use one of the many Ajax techniques available (the XMLHttpRequest object is probably most sensible)
2. Once the data arrives on the server, it must be stored somehow. This would typically use a database.
3. When Bob visits page 2, it must be generated by the server using the data from the database

You could skip step three by having step two generate a plain HTML file and write it to the location of page 2. I wouldn't recommend this approach though, databases are usually easier to manage and debug.

Comment: Alright- a bit of explanation: The data is actually created in a `form` whose `action` attribute, say, is `page1.php` (so the data is sent to `page1.php`) Now I need this data in `page2.php`. `page1.php` is not linked to `page2.php`

Comment: If you've got a form, why does your question ask to do it without using a form? Anyway, just submit the data *somewhere* and store it in a database. Have page2 read the data out of the database.

Comment: First, thank you very much for the solution. Second, my question says I don't have a `form` because I need to transfer the data from `page1.php` to `page2.php` (and not from the `form` itself- because the action of the form is set to `page1.php`). So mentioning where `page1.php` gets the data from seemed like an extra, not necessary detail to me. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a database to store the data sent by the form or you can even store the data in a file (maybe a csv to read it more easily) if you don't have access to a database.

With a **database**:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

With a **simple file**:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php
If you use a file remember to append and eventually clean it on read.

Comment: What's better? File or database?

Comment: It depends on the type of data that you want to pass, a file is faster if the informations to store are simple and few. If you have a lot of values to store and you want to do some elaboration on them you should go with the database.

Comment: It is just a single small two-word string variable. So I'll go with the file because it seems easier as well.

Comment: Does "eventually cleaning the file on read" mean removing the contents of the file or deleting the file itself?

Comment: It's indifferent, but if your host have limits on single file size, depending on the growth ratio of your file you should definitely clean it once in a while.
Also remember that almost all hosts have limits on disk usage.

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to ask again if you encounter troubles.

Answer (score 1):

Information must reside in server side.

1. Page 1 sends variable using Ajax OR variable is saved on page 1 execution
2. Server stores information in database
3. Page 2 is loaded with variable while processing OR Page 2 gets variable using Ajax.